# How do I find out my Outlook mailbox size limit?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, quota

We're using Outlook 2003 with Exchange.  I want to know what my mailbox quota size is.  (Yes, I realize I can ask the systems guys, but assume that's not feasible here.)  Is there any way within Outlook to find out what my mailbox **limit** is?  I know how big it is (Mailbox > Properties > Folder Size), I just want to know what the quota is.

And no, I'm not going to fill it up with crap until I get an email telling me what the quota is. ;-) I'm looking for a mechanism within Outlook to just see the actual data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article : ["Relating Mailbox sizes to Mailbox quotas"](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2005/03/relating-mailbox-sizes-to-mailbox.html).
The basic answer is that you'll need to run a script to find out the quota.

The above article points to this other article that you shouldn't miss:
[How to programmatically get the size of mailboxes in Exchange](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320071).
It contains several scripts to do that using different technologies.

Comment: I suppose this does answer the question, although it's not really feasible for me to do it this way.  I was hoping there was a menu option somewhere in Outlook that would tell me. :)  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS Outlook 2010, you can select File -> Info. Mailbox Cleanup section shows the size limit and free space left.

Comment: Same for outlook 2013.